# Alternate profile language in LinkedIn API not working

Tags: linkedin-api

[According to the LinkedIn API docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin), the user's profile can be retrieved in multiple languages. This is done by adding a Accept-Language header on the request. I provided a Korean translation to [my profile](https://www.linkedin.com/in/daniel-john-gomez-971b92118?locale=ko_KR) and included the header but the response is still in English.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your header value does have the wrong syntax. It should be ko-KR instead of ko_KR.

Also double-check that the second part is correct. For example, en-GB will not return a profile in US English, only en-US will. Other variations fall back to the default language which might not be English at all.